# Stormworks Lua problem with global variables

Tags: lua

I am using Stormworks embedded Lua. I have encountered an error when attempting to draw a line to a screen:

[image: error]

My code:

```lua
function onDraw()
    w = screen.getWidth()                
    h = screen.getHeight()
end

function onTick()       
    tar1 = input.getBool(1)
    tar2 = input.getBool(2)
    az1 = input.getNumber(2)
    h1 = input.getNumber(3)
    az2 = input.getNumber(6)
    h2 = input.getNumber(7)
    az1 = az1 * 10 * w
    h1 = h1 * 10 * h
    az2 = az2 * 10 * w
    h2 = h2 * 10 * h
end

-- Draw function that will be executed when this script renders to a screen
function onDraw()
    w = screen.getWidth()                 -- Get the screen's width and height
    h = screen.getHeight()                  
    screen.setColor(0, 255, 0)           -- Set draw color to green
    if tar1 == True then
        screen.drawLine(az1,h1,az1,h1)
    end
end
```

I tried finding info on how global variables work in Lua, and tried fixing the problem by using my knowledge of Python, but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Before being initialized, global variables in Lua default to the value `nil`.

```lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> w
nil
```

The error indicates that on this line

```lua
az1 = az1 * 10 * w
```

the value of `w` is still `nil`.

`w` is only given a value when `onDraw` is executed. This means `onTick` is executing at least once before `onDraw`.

*Note that defining `onDraw` twice causes the second function to 'replace' the first.*

You should initialize your variables beforehand, so there is no chance of performing multiplication with a `nil` value. Since either function relies on values provided from the other, there are a few ways to do this, but you could start by doing something like

```lua
local should_display = false 

local x1 = 0 
local y1 = 0         

local x2 = 0         
local y2 = 0         
                                      
function onTick()        
    should_display = input.getBool(1)
    
    x1 = input.getNumber(2) * 10        
    y1 = input.getNumber(3) * 10                  
    x2 = input.getNumber(6) * 10                  
    y2 = input.getNumber(7) * 10                  
end                                               

function onDraw()            
    if should_display then
        local width = screen.getWidth()
        local height = screen.getHeight()

        screen.setColor(0, 255, 0)
        screen.drawLine(x1 * width, y1 * height, x2 * width, y2 * height)
    end                                                                          
end
```

where the final calculation is performed within `onDraw`.

*Note that, unless your calls to `input.getNumber` are returning fractional values, multiplying any value `>= 1` by the return value of `screen.getWidth` or `screen.getHeight` is going to be larger than the screen dimensions.*